# Excel Reducing the Size of a Dataset by Averaging one Column Based on the Value in Another Column With Random Repetition

Tags: excel, average

I have a large dataset that looks similar to columns A and B below. The repetition in column A is not constant but it is increasing order. I want to reduce the number of rows in my dataset by averaging the values in column B for each increasing value in A such as what is shown in columns D & E. I have found examples for this when column A changes every 10 rows or whatever, but not for when that varies.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You might consider using a pivot table, or `AVERAGEIFS`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen. I'm just not sure how to have the criteria value in the AVERAGEIF statement vary based on the value in column A.

Comment: `UNIQUE` may be useful.

Comment: @user11222393 I'll take a look and see if I can adapt that to my data.

Comment: Ok. Anybody know how I can do the same thing in R?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact reason why the "subtotals" feature has been implemented:

[image]

Result (after clicking on <kbd>2</kbd> in the margin):

[image]

Have fun!